# "In memory of" vs "To the memory of"

Tags: idioms, dedications

Is there a difference in usage between "In memory of" and "To the memory of"? For instance, is one used for full sentences and the other used for fragments and dedications?

- "This book is dedicated (to the memory of/in memory of) my father"
- "(In memory of/To the memory of) my father"

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+memory+of%2C+to+the+memory+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20memory%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20memory%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows that "to the" was historically more common but that has changed as dedications become less common.

[image: Ngrams]

Comment: @Mari-LouA fixed and embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, you have to say 'dedicated to the memory of' as the verb 'to dedicate' uses the preposition 'to'.

In the second sentence, you could say either, but - in my opinion - the meaning is very subtly different. 'To the memory of my father' sounds as if you decided to dedicate the book to your father prior to having started to write it. Additionally, the book and its contents likely have some sort of relation to him. By reading the book, you are keeping some element of his being alive. It might be a historical book about the town he grew up in, for example.

'In memory of my father' sounds more general: you just want to dedicate the book to him - neither the book nor its contents has any meaningful connection to him.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure how widespread your interpretation is, but it sounds good to me. FYI, I went with the complete sentence 'This book is dedicated to the memory of...'.